# URL RewriteEngine Internal Server Error

Tags: .htaccess

I'm using the following configuration in `.htaccess` to try to rewrite URLs of the form `http://www.mysite.com/subdir/page.php?param=4` to `http://www.mysite.com/subdir/page/param/4`:

```
# Turn on the rewrite engine
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# Request routing
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_-]*)$   index.php?name=$1 [nc,qsa]
```

However, I get an Internal Server Error when I visit the page. Is there something wrong with the configuration?

EDIT: I've updated it to the following, but now it does not seem to be doing any rewriting and gives me a 404 when I try to use a URL like `http://www.mysite.com/subdir/param/2`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=([0-9]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^project-testing/ws/index.php$ /project-testing/ws/name/%1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: What url you are requesting to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `%{QUERY_STRING}` to read the query string of your URL to redirect based on it.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^param=([0-9]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^subdir/page.php$ subdir/page/param/%1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Or if you want that accessing:

```
http://www.mysite.com/subdir/page/param/4
```

Shows the content of:

```
http://www.mysite.com/subdir/page.php?param=4
```

Then it would be like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^subdir/page/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ subdir/page.php?$1=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: I've used the following code (modified for my actual URL based on what you've written here): Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=([0-9]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^project-testing/ws/index.php$ /project-testing/ws/name/%1 [R=301,NC,L]`

But it doesn't work. It just says "page not found" as if there's no rewriting being done.

Comment: @rar [update your question with the modified code you tried as its unreadable on the comments.](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22596628/edit)

Comment: @rar is name value a number or can also be a string and what URL are you trying to access that results in 404? The first one you mention on your question? If you want to access `http://www.mysite.com/subdir/page/param/4` you have to use the 2nd example I gave you on my answer, read carefully :)

Comment: `name` can be a string (in this example, the only available data means it WILL be a string), and the rewritten URL is the one I'm trying to access. So `http://www.mysite.com/subdir/page/param/4`.

Comment: @rar Use the 2nd rule only, that I've posted on my answer.

Comment: I got it working but I had to remove the `RewriteBase` as well as the directories within the URLs in the rules. Thanks~